# Best way to render multiple videos on WPF

Tags: directx, ms-media-foundation, direct2d, dxva, wpf-mediakit

I am a newbie on this all stuff related with DirectX, render video, render images and so on..
So I need your help:

I have a WPF application. This application needs to render a lot of videos (at least 10 videos in parallel) and this videos must be render on GPU, not CPU. I already tried to use WPF-MediaKit but it consumes a lot of memory(RAM) and CPU. I also tried the WPF MediaElement and it also consumes a lot of memory(RAM).

So, my question is:
**1 - How you build an application to render a lot of video at the same time on GPU with the minimum of possible memory? What technologies would you use?**

Note: If you suggest more than one technology/tools that need to work together, can you explain how they work together, please (Like I'm so dumb)?! For example: To render a video and show it on screen you need to use EVR with DXVA, ... because .... **OR** if you can give me some application examples, I was very grateful.. :) (Sorry but working in low-level is still a little bit hard for me and I need some orientation on this)

Comment: I think this is not a WPF problem. The number of videos you can play at the same time depends on the format/encoding of the videos. If you have 10 FullHD Videos in H.264 then you need a really powerfull machine. If the video is decoded in CPU or GPU depends on your decoder.

Comment: oh yes, I know that this is not a WPF problem! What I want to know is: How you build an application to render a lot of video at the same time? What technologies would you use? I will edit my text and change the question :)

Comment: The newest WPF-MediaKit has performance improvements and also see your own issue https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit/issues/24